# Can't print .prn file using cmd on network printer

Tags: printing, copy, cmd, network-printers

I'm trying print prn file in my c# program. To do it I'm trying first find solution to command that allow me print prn file on network printer. So here is command that I'm actualy use:

```
print C:\test\test.prn > "\\10.0.2.152\Brother DCP-7065DN Printer"
```

I also try another command:

```
copy /B C:\test\test.prn "\\10.0.2.152\Brother DCP-7065DN Printer"
```

In both cases after few seconds cmd showing message:

```
Cannot find network path.
```

But both command work in case when I use PDFCreator as printer. So when I write `\\developer3.idtt.local\PDFCreator` instead of `"\\10.0.2.152\Brother DCP-7065DN Printer"` then file can be "printed".

---

### Now some additional information:

- **developer3.idtt.local** is a my full computer name.
- **10.0.2.152** is ip adress of Brother printer and it answer on ping command.
- **Brother DCP-7065DN Printer** is the target printer and it is checked as shared printer in preferences.
- **Printer port**:

[image]
[image]

### Question:

How solve this problem? Are you have any idea why this printer cannot be find by cmd?

Comment: Did you try to map the printer as LPT1?
`net use LPT1 \\10.0.2.152\Brother DCP-7065DN Printer`
and then `copy C:\test\test.prn LPT1`

Comment: Actually yes and got this error: `System error 66. The network resource type is not correct`

Comment: After some modification command print work, but in query it only show for less than 1 sec and disapear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ok problem solved!

If I check print as shared printer you should call your computer name instead of printer IP. In my case correct command is:

`copy C:\\test\\test.prn /B \\Developer3\TSC`

where **Developer3** is my computer name and **TSC** is `shareName` of printer. Also **don't forget** to use printer for this type of file (in my example I tested on thermal printer) otherwise you can got clear page.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how to avoid printing a clear page?  We are attempting to print a text file on the same model, DCP-7065DN.  Thanks very much